# Stocks with buyers only

Tags: stocks, india, financial-literacy

I have Alok Industries stock NSE in my portfolio, everyday it increases by a fixed percent 4.95 and moneycotrol websites states everyday that "buyers only". What's the matter and will I face any problem in selling it

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in selling,  I haven't seen anything like buyers only... its many people are bullish and there is a buying sentiment on the stock

Answer (score 0):

This means that there are one or more people who want to buy this stock, but can't because there is nobody who wants to sell it. So the buyer(s) raise(s) their price by 4.95% every day, hoping to persuade some stockholders (like you) to sell the stock to them.

If you want to get rid of this stock, then you should be able to take them up on the offer. Unless, of course, they change their mind or find someone else who sells the stock to them.